# Forms in symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

I am a beginner with symfony, and I can not get my head around forms generation. In theory there even is a form framework, to have complete flexibility. **But**, as far as I understand, forms are rendered as tables in symfony. I am used to CakePHP where I can output input elements one at a time, and then wrap them as I wish: in tables, divs, whatever, or, more often than not, nothing, and just use CSS to position them correctly.

I am a bit appalled at the fact that a framework with such high standards on code quality then outputs HTML tables where they are not needed. I guess I'm just missing something.

> Is there a way to output forms as forms, without extra HTML tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A default formatter for `sfForm::render()` is [`sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterTable`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterTable). That's why your forms has been rendered as table when you used `echo $form`.

1. [A Gentle Introduction to symfony: Chapter 10 - Forms](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms)
2. [Practical symfony - Day 10: The Forms](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10)
3. [The More with symfony book: Advanced Forms](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms)
4. [`sfForm::renderUsing()`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfForm#method_renderusing)
5. [`sfWidgetFormSchema::setDefaultFormFormatterName()`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormSchema#method_setdefaultformformattername)
6. Tones of other resources all over the Internet